# Is it possible to map @Published to @Binding?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
final class State: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isSelected = false
    @Published var selectedColor: Color = .white
}

private enum Constants {
    static let colors: [Color] = [.black, .white, .blue, .green, .yellow, .red]
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: Constants.spacing) {
        HStack {
            Eraser()

            ForEach(Constants.colors, id: \.self) { color in
                PaintColor(color: color, isSelected:  $state.isSelected)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .padding(Constants.colorsInsets)
    }
    .background(Constants.backgroundColor)
}
```

What I would actually like to do set `isSelected` on `PaintColor` to `true` or `false` based on the value of `selectedColor`. Is it possible to `map` a `@Published` property? I want to do something like:

```
PaintColor(color: color, isSelected: state.selectedColor == color)
```

Comment: Change class to struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with computable Binding, like

```
PaintColor(color: color, isSelected:  Binding(
   get: { state.selectedColor == color },
   set: { state.selectedColor = $0 ? color : .white }
))
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

*actually if it is possible all unselected then it is needed to make selectedColor optional (and then reset to `nil` instead of `.white` above)

```
@Published var selectedColor: Color? = .white
```